# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'likes'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the count of likes related to post so I created the following: **Post Model:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I am already able to get the no. of likes but I am trying a different method, I am just trying to know how the method works.

**Here are the views where I try to add to it when a like is made**

```
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    post = request.POST.get('post_id')
    current_likes = post.likes    <------------Error coming from here

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post)
        if user in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(user)
            current_likes = current_likes - 1

        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(user)
            current_likes = current_likes + 1
        post.likes=current_likes
        post.save()

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post_id=post)
        if not created:
            if like.value == 'Like':
                like.value = 'Unlike'
            else:
                like.value = 'Like'
        like.save()
        context = {
            'post': post,
        }
    return redirect('blog:post-detail', slug=post_obj.slug)
```

**The issue now is that I am receiving**

```
AttributeError at /blogs/like
'str' object has no attribute 'likes'
```

I have tried to fix it but I don't know-how.
**The source of error is highlighted here:**

```
current_likes = post.likes
```

Comment: `post` is not a `Post` object, but a `str`ing. `request.GET` and `request.POST` are `QueryDict`s, these only thus contain strings.

Comment: You can use `post_obj.likes`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part doesn't make much sense:

```
post = request.POST.get('post_id')
current_likes = post.likes

if request.method == 'POST':
    post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post)
```

as you are accessing the `request.POST` before you even check if the request method is a `POST`. Change it to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    post = request.POST.get('post_id')
    post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post)
    current_likes = post_obj.likes
```

Answer (score 2):

`post` is *not* a `Post` object, it is simply the `str`ing that maps on the `post_id` key. You can fetch the corresponding `Post` object with `get

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def like_post(request):
    user = request.user
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    current_likes = post.likes
    # …
```

In the later part of the view, you of course do not need to fetch the `Post` object a second time.

If GET requests are allowed as well, it might however be better to encode the primary key in the URL, and not in the POST request, since you can also make a GET request, and then the `post_id` will be missing.

The URL is thus normally:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/blogs/like/<int:pk>', like_post, name='like')
]
```

and then in the `like_post` view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def like_post(request, post_id):
    user = request.user
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    current_likes = post.likes
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: @Selcuk: yes, but that is *after the `post.current_likes` is used. Furthermore it is a bad idea to use a POST parameter for the `post_id`, since in a GET request, that will not be part of the item.

Comment: True, but for a `like` action which is supposed to modify state it makes sense to exclusively use a `POST`.

Comment: @Selcuk: well with a REST API, I would expect that a GET request can retrieve the (number of) likes for a given POST. After all the idea of REST is to focus on the entities, and provide methods for these entities.

Comment: I see but the view in the question does not do anything if the request method is not `POST` anyway. It is not designed to handle `GET` at all.

Comment: @Selcuk: no indeed, which is a bit pitty :( If that's the case it might be better to restrict the HTTP methods.